# How to reshape a dataframe with duplicated rows into rownames and colnames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been struggling with reshaping the following dataframe:

```
geneSymbol <- c(rep("gene1",4),rep("gene2",4),rep("gene3",4))
Sample_name <- rep(c("sample1","sample2","sample3","sample4"),3)
log2FC <- c(1.5,-1.0,0.5,0.2,-0.3,-0.7,-0.12,0.33,0.64,-0.17,2.3,-1.7)
df <- data.frame(geneSymbol, Sample_name, log2FC)
> df
   geneSymbol Sample_name log2FC
1       gene1     sample1   1.50
2       gene1     sample2  -1.00
3       gene1     sample3   0.50
4       gene1     sample4   0.20
5       gene2     sample1  -0.30
6       gene2     sample2  -0.70
7       gene2     sample3  -0.12
8       gene2     sample4   0.33
9       gene3     sample1   0.64
10      gene3     sample2  -0.17
11      gene3     sample3   2.30
12      gene3     sample4  -1.70
```

where the 'geneSymbol' and 'Sample_name' columns have duplicated rows for each. I have been trying to reshape this dataframe into a dataframe which has the 'geneSymbol' as its rownames and the 'Sample_name' as its colnames, which should look as follows:

```
      sample1  sample2  sample3  sample4
gene1    1.50    -1.00     0.50     0.20
gene2   -0.30    -0.70    -0.12     0.33
gene3    0.64    -0.17     2.30    -1.70
```

I manually crete this table myself, but I have no idea which function I need to use to make this dataframe or table from `df` with lines of code as I have hundreds of rows in my dataframe. I would really appreciate it if anyone can help this out for me.

Best wishes,
TJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using **tidyr**:

```
  tidyr::pivot_wider(df,values_from =  'log2FC',names_from = 'Sample_name')

  geneSymbol sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
  gene1         1.5    -1       0.5     0.2 
  gene2        -0.3    -0.7    -0.12    0.33
  gene3         0.64   -0.17    2.3    -1.7
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
xtabs(log2FC ~ geneSymbol + Sample_name, df)

          Sample_name
geneSymbol sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
     gene1    1.50   -1.00    0.50    0.20
     gene2   -0.30   -0.70   -0.12    0.33
     gene3    0.64   -0.17    2.30   -1.70
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `acast`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df, geneSymbol ~ Sample_name, value.var = 'log2FC')
      sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
gene1    1.50   -1.00    0.50    0.20
gene2   -0.30   -0.70   -0.12    0.33
gene3    0.64   -0.17    2.30   -1.70
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `data.table` pendant using `dcast`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
dcast(df, geneSymbol ~ Sample_name, value.var = "log2FC")
```

```
   geneSymbol sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
1:      gene1    1.50   -1.00    0.50    0.20
2:      gene2   -0.30   -0.70   -0.12    0.33
3:      gene3    0.64   -0.17    2.30   -1.70
```